# MVC 4 View open another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I am using MVC 4 with some Kendo UI and I am new to both.
What I need is for my Kendo grid to redirect to another page when a row is clicked.

My initial thought was to create a function within the script section of the view that the grid is on and that function would call the other view that I need. However, I am not sure if this is possible because I believe the view is supposed to be separate from the controller.

I think that I need to somehow make all of this be able to work from within the controller but I am not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Ajax.ActionLink to call controller and receive partialView

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a post action you can use RedirectToAction() in your controller.  If you need to change the window in JavaScript see below.

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("(Action)","(Controller)",new {id= (params)})";
```

Comment: What I would like to do is call my ManageProcess method of the Home Controller when grid row is selected. I'm not sure how to set it up doing a post action, but that sounds like it might be the right way to go.

Comment: Gotcha.  If you can post up your view code and controller I can probably help you do that